# Vue is returning [object Module] to img src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS in version 2.6.11 with vue-material 1.0.0-beta-11.

I've read through the internet about loading images into Vue through vue-loader etc. but none of that helped.

```
<md-card-media md-ratio="4:3">
      <img :src="getImgUrl(muscle.name)" alt="Skyscraper">
</md-card-media>
```

This is my HTML element which is supposed to render images.

The getImgUrl is defined in such a way:

```
methods: {
    getImgUrl: imgName => {
      let urlName = imgName.replace(/\s/g, '')
      return require(`@/assets/images/${urlName}.png`)
    }
}
```

The result of the code above:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,dmFyIHJlbmRlciwgc3RhdGljUmVuZGVyRm5zCnZhc...truncatedForReadibility" alt="Skyscraper" crossorigin="Anonymous">
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/siluets/',
    configureWebpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        esModule: false,

                    },
                },
            ],
        }

    }
}
```

The browser is not showing up any images. I can't figure it out by myself

Comment: Please provide your `webpack.config.js` or `vue.config.js`

Comment: I don't recommend using methods in template content; they get run every tick. Try using a computed property instead

Comment: @Ashish provided after edit

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct element? I ask as your source does not have that `crossorigin` attribute

Comment: Why are you using the vue-loader for images? Why did you add that rule at all? Webpack is configured to load images via the `url-loader` / `file-loader` by default

Comment: @Phil I've tried to do it by file-loader instead of vue-loader and it still results in the same problem. 

Images are under the src/assets/files in the project.

Comment: @Phil without any rules, all I get is <img src="[object Module]" .../>

Comment: @Phill I’ve mean src/assets/images

Comment: Can you please give some examples of what `muscle.name` could be as well as examples of the files in `src/assets/images`?

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue with a standard Vue CLI project (making some assumptions about `muscle.name` and the images you have) and I could not find any problems ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-burnell-8419q. Please address the above comment asking for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use **vue-loader** for images. Use **url-loader** or **file-loader** as shown os docs:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules

Answer (score 0):

You can access the image url in the [object Module] using the dot notation to access the `default` property.

In your `getImgUrl` method you can do this by returning: `` require(`@/assets/images/${urlName}.png`).default ``

```js
methods: {
    getImgUrl: imgName => {
      let urlName = imgName.replace(/\s/g, '')
      return require(`@/assets/images/${urlName}.png`).default
    }
}
```